# C++ "new T[size]" doesn't work?

Tags: c++

I have a template class defined as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class tbufferpool {
private:
    const int m_initial;
    const int m_size;
    const int m_total;
    T *m_buffer;
    vector<T*> m_queue;

public:
    // constructor
    tbufferpool(int initial, int size) : m_initial(initial), m_size(size), m_total(initial*size) {
        m_buffer = new T[m_total];
        T* next_buffer = m_buffer;
        for (int i = 0; i < initial; ++i, next_buffer += size) {
            m_queue.push_back(next_buffer);
        }
    }
```

and at some point in the constructor I do:

```
m_buffer = new T[size];
```

This works for most use-cases but in one test I get the following memory error reported by valgrind (command and relevant snippet below) the test still passes fine though. The interesting bit is `operator new(unsigned long)` meaning it is not allocating and aligning for the concrete T type I setup "double" as I expected but for `unsigned long`? If I modify my bufferpool implementation and hard-code `new double[size]` then this memory error doesn't show but of course I only work with `tbufferpool<double>` now.

Can anyone advice how to fix this? the `new T[size]` should be legal right? since the template parameters is applied at compile time by the pre-processor that creates a new class for each template type used. Would this be a compiler bug?

The test_matrix is a suite containing 30 test cases. Only one test produces the problem shown below in valgrind, that test passes nevertheless. I checked all the inputs to the function call where the problem originates using the `new T[size]` variant and printed them alongside the same inputs using `new double[size]` variant. I compare them using AraxisMerge and they are identical. I'm afraid is a problem related to the memory alignment turning out different depending whether I use the template parameter or the concrete double type ... ?

```
$ valgrind --show-reachable=yes --dsymutil=yes --track-origins=yes ./test_matrix
  [snip]
  ==3719== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
  ==3719==    at 0x3BE86C8: mkl_blas_dscal (in /opt/intel/composerxe-2011.4.184/mkl/lib/libmkl_mc3.dylib)
  ==3719==    by 0x432FFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
  ==3719==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
  ==3719==    at 0xD62F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
  ==3719==    by 0x97B15C: operator new(unsigned long) (in /opt/local/lib/gcc46/libstdc++.6.dylib)
  ==3719==    by 0x7FFF5FBFE54F: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x10014BDBF: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x7FFF5FBFE58F: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x97B288: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /opt/local/lib/gcc46/libstdc++.6.dylib)
  ==3719==    by 0x7FFF5FBFE58F: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x100013853: tbufferpool<double>::tbufferpool(int, int) (bufferpool.h:30)
  ==3719==    by 0x7003FFFFF: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x100079E7F: ??? (in ./test_matrix)
  ==3719==    by 0x7FFF5FBFE58F: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x10014BE0F: ???
  ==3719== 
  ==3719== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
  ==3719==    at 0x3BE86CA: mkl_blas_dscal (in /opt/intel/composerxe-2011.4.184/mkl/lib/libmkl_mc3.dylib)
  ==3719==    by 0x432FFFFFFFFFFFFF: ???
  ==3719==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
  ==3719==    at 0xD62F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
  ==3719==    by 0x97B15C: operator new(unsigned long) (in /opt/local/lib/gcc46/libstdc++.6.dylib)
  ==3719==    by 0x7FFF5FBFE54F: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x10014BDBF: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x7FFF5FBFE58F: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x97B288: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /opt/local/lib/gcc46/libstdc++.6.dylib)
  ==3719==    by 0x7FFF5FBFE58F: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x100013853: tbufferpool<double>::tbufferpool(int, int) (bufferpool.h:30)
  ==3719==    by 0x7003FFFFF: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x100079E7F: ??? (in ./test_matrix)
  ==3719==    by 0x7FFF5FBFE58F: ???
  ==3719==    by 0x10014BE0F: ???
  [snip]
```

System details:

```
/Users/bravegag/code/fastcode_project/build_debug$ uname -a && g++ --version
Darwin Macintosh-4.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; 
root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
g++ (GCC) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe it is because `double` is of the same size as `unsigned long`.

Comment: Please try to isolate problem (one instantiation of `tbufferpool` template with type double, remove as much as possible from constructor) and repost the code. Most important is how `size` is initialized.

Comment: That means that you haven't initialized some portion of that allocated memory, but you should have done it. Are you initializing that allocated memory?

Comment: The `unsigned long` argument doesn't have anything to do with your problem. The `new` operator does two things, first it calls `operator new(size_t)` to allocate the raw storage, and then calls the constructors of the allocated objects (trivial in your case). So the `unsigned long` argument is perfectly correct (assuming your `size_t` is a typedef for `unsigned long`, which is reasonable), as it is just the size of the allocated storage and doesn't have anything to do with the type of the allocated objects. So your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: any reason why you don't check ctor args `initial` and `size` for being sensible (non-negative and not too large)?

Comment: indeed good catch, I will fix it, using a simple assert will suffice. Note that this is not public API though, this is in the very core of my framework and this class implementation is not exposed.

Comment: Titles like "new doesn't work" drive me nuts.  Of course it works.  You think you're the first person to ever try using it?

Comment: lol :) if you look carefully the "doesn't work" refers to the fact of doing a new on a template parameter T and this is not so commonly used IMHO.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua It is indeed quite common to use templates together with dynamic allocation, I think. But templates don't really change the workings of new, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note the difference between

```
m_buffer = new T[size];
```

and

```
m_buffer = new T[size]();
```

In the former case the array is not initialised, hence your valgrind error:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value
```

That said, from my experience you can ignore this particular valgrind output in this case. As you obviously use some kind of blas implementation, most likely it is the effect of an optimisation inside your BLAS library and won't do bad things.

Comment: wow fantastic! your suggestions solves the problem! I'm using g++ and gcc latest version in Mac OS X 4.6.3

Answer (score 2):

Your issue doesn't relate to the memory allocation per se. Valgrind says you are using unitialized values from the array pointed to by `m_buffer`. You can get the same with

```
T value;
// use value
```

or

```
T values[size];
// use values
```

To fix the issue you'll need to initialize your buffer with appropriate values after memory allocation, e.g.

```
m_buffer = new T[size];
std::fill_n(m_buffer, size, T());
```

```
m_buffer = new T[size](); // doesn't work in gcc3.x.x
```

or just use std::vector instead.